# flot.axislabels: how to choose labels' colors?

Tags: jquery-mobile, flot, axis-labels

I am using flot with the plugin "jquery.flot.axislabels.js", but I can't find other documentation than the README file.
So the general question is "where can I find some complete documentation ?"
And the more specific one is: "How to set the label's color ?"
Some properties are available, such as "axisLabelFontSizePixels", "axisLabelFontFamily", etc... so I've tried "axisLabelColor" and "axisLabelFontColor" without any result.

I tried to use CSS too, according to this: http://people.mozilla.com/~mcote/flot-axislabels/example/
But it does not work either. Maybe CSS is working with an older version of axislabel.js.

Ideally I'd avoid doing this with CSS, I guess that if we are able to choose the font we are able to choose the color. But I cant find what syntax I have to use...

If someone knows something, I'd be glad to read it :-)
Thanks and regards,
S.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From looking at the source code it doesn't look like the plugin provides that option in either of it's two modes of operation:

1.) Draw the labels using the canvas - no ability to set color (only font family and size).  If you are handy with JavaScript adding color wouldn't be too difficult.  (You are probably using this option since it explains why your CSS doesn't work.)

2.) Draw the labels using HTML DIVs.  This is what your linked example does. In it the author specifies the color through an inline CSS tag.  How I would do it though to keep it all together is after your plot call:

```
  $('.yaxisLabel').css('color','red');
  $('.y2axisLabel').css('color','orange');
  $('.y3axisLabel').css('color','green');
  $('.y4axisLabel').css('color','purple');
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CxhhT/).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, this is the answer: "axisLabelUseCanvas: true" must be removed if we want to be able to set the color of the labels. For info, "axisLabelUseHtml: true" (which I've tried) is not better. Just don't set any of them. Seems simple but I tried many options before ;-)

Comment: Those classes didnt work for me. But I checked the code and found this to work `$('.flot-y1-axis').css('color','#00b3e3');` etc for y1, y2, y3

Answer (score 2):

I found it simpler to just add `!important` targeting the classes generated by flot. For targeting axis, you can aim for `.yaxisLabel` or `.xaxisLabel`, or for the whole thing target `.flot-text`.

```
.flot-text {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has one accepted answer, but just thought of sharing how I eventually got it working.

FLot version: Flot 0.8.3

I had to explicitly set `axisLabelUseCanvas:false` and then write a bit of jQuery code:

`$('.flot-tick-label').css('color','red');`

And there we go, after couple of hours of frustration, it was finally red!

Hope this helps someone who is lost in Flot.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `axisLabelUseCanvas:false` explicitly and use `$('.axisLabels').css('color','red');`  to make them red